# CSS and image not loading in jsp

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am running a web application in Apache Tomcat 7 everything works good but my images and css are not loading when I checked my JSP file. The path to the css and images are correct but when I run it tomcat is not loading the css and image files.

Here is my project structure
- Student 
     - images
           - logo.png
      - stylesheets
            - style.css
      - WEB-INF
             - JSP
                 - login.jsp

In my login.jsp
I have given the link to image

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Can you add the paths such as JSP files, images and CSS files, otherwise it would be very difficult to guess. Best would be explain your project layout.

Comment: Your problem isn't  clearly understood from your question, please provide image of your project structure and code for your login.jsp